# R open plotly in standalone window

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I would like to display a plotly plot object in a standalone window that behaves similarly to the window that pops up using the base R `plot()` function.

Using a basic example from the plotly website:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
     geom_point(aes(text = paste("Clarity:", clarity))) +
     geom_smooth(aes(colour = cut, fill = cut)) + facet_wrap(~ cut)

p2 <- ggplotly(p)
```

The `p2` object is an `htmlwidget` object and I get some control over its display using the `sizingPolicy` element as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/vignettes/develop_sizing.html). However, I can't find anything that allows me to set the viewer/browser to something other than my current browser (as a new tab) or within RStudio.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid applications outside of R packages to launch a separate window from within R. However, I would also be happy with figuring out how to granularly control browser output to display `p2` as a new window in kiosk or app mode (see the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/459775/how-can-i-launch-a-browser-with-no-window-frame-or-tabs-address-bar) for some examples of kiosk/app mode).

**Edit:** Although I mentioned RStudio when discussing some of the options that I was able to find, I am talking about using R from a simple console. That said, granular display options should hopefully be independent of the user interface.

Comment: Are you talking about usage in R-Studio? Seems you are, but `plot` does not open a new window in R-Studio. Unless there is an option I don't know about (probably). And why is displaying an `htmlwidget` in a browser not the same as what you are asking for?

Comment: @MikeWise This would be for usage outside of R-Studio. Displaying in a browser would be sufficient, if I could get some control over that display -- opening a new page in kiosk or app mode. The default behaviour of tacking another tab to the 20 I might have open and moving my browser to the current virtual workspace is not particularly convenient.

Comment: Hmm, you could try appending another extension to your file (like they do with `.svg` in your `htmlwidget` link under `forceNetwork`), registering that extension to another browser that you don't use. Maybe that would get you what you want?

Comment: @MikeWise I think this is a little over my head, but it looks like the `.svg` handling  in `forceNetwork` is being defined in JS for a new widget. In my case, I'd assume that all the JS would handled by the plotly.js library, although perhaps there could be a way to add new methods. Either way, it's worth looking into more, thanks. I also need to figure out what is actually making the call to open the browser tab and maybe see if there are any available options there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working solution, but I'll be happy to change the accepted answer if someone has anything better.

I defined a print function that can be used to launch a custom browser command for an `htmlwidget` object. In this case, I used `chromium-browser -app=...`, but the overall approach should be general.

```
print_app <- function(widget) {

  # Generate random file name
  temp <- paste(tempfile('plotly'), 'html', sep = '.')

  # Save. Note, leaving selfcontained=TRUE created files that froze my browser
  htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget, temp, selfcontained = FALSE)

  # Launch with desired application
  system(sprintf("chromium-browser -app=file://%s", temp))

  # Return file name if it's needed for any other purpose
  temp
}
```

Combining with the previous example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
     geom_point(aes(text = paste("Clarity:", clarity))) +
     geom_smooth(aes(colour = cut, fill = cut)) + facet_wrap(~ cut)

p2 <- ggplotly(p)
print_app(p2)
```

It seems like `htmlwidgets` normally uses the `html_print` function from `htmltools`, which in turn selects the browser to use via `getOption("viewer", utils::browseURL)`, which bakes in a lot of the browser selection options -- making it challenging to change.

The idea for saving the html file locally came from this `plotly` issue: [saving plotly plots locally?](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/294).

Comment: How are you running this? With `rscript`? And what system are you using?

Comment: @MikeWise I'm using Linux (Mint and Arch) and I usually run commands or source scripts in the basic interactive R shell. I just checked and it works with RStudio and Rscript as well. Not sure about any other OS though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS, change this line in @ssokolen's answer

```
 # Launch with desired application
 system(sprintf("chromium-browser -app=file://%s", temp))
```

to

```
 system(sprintf("open -a 'google chrome'  /%s", temp))
```

Works in zsh in MacOs Catalina with the Intellij R plugin.